# set attribute 'src' to an element in html using nodejs

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express, web

I use 'express' nodejs and using this code to send url into text

```
<form method="GET" action='/download' class="my-5">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="exampleInputEmail1"
                    >Link:</label
                >
                <input
                    type="text"
                    class="form-control"
                    placeholder="Enter URL"
                    name="url"
                />
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Download</button>
        </form>
```

in my project I receive

```
    const express = require("express");
const app = express();
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    return res.render("index");
});
app.get("/download", async(req, res) => {
    console.log(req.query.url);
});


app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log("Server is running on http://localhost:3000");
});
```

as you can see I use get '/download' to receive url from input and doing some analazing to output new url

my quation is : how can I set this new url to an arttibute 'src' for element (such as img) in homepage without loading new page?

I need only put this new url to be value in 'src' for img in index.eje

Comment: Use AJAX in the client. Then use `img.src = response;` in the function that processes the response.

Comment: I'm using nodejs for first time.
I do'nt undrstand you :(

Comment: You don't do this on the server, you do it on the client. It has nothing to do with node.js, as the server has no access to the DOM.

Comment: so how can I do it on the client? 
I try with javascritp but no resualt

Comment: `img.src = response`, where `response` is the response you received from the AJAX request, and `img` is a variable that's set to the `<img>` element you want to change.

Answer (score 0):

```
app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    return res.render("index",
        {
            srcAttr: 'link to image'
        }
    );
});
```

```html
<img src="<%= srcAttr %>">
```